# Wordpress meta query on sqlite not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sqlite

I develop a site with wordpress and mysql. That set up is locally. On then server where I host my site(at a university) they use sqlite. I use this plugin to make wordpress work with Sqlite:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/sqlite-integration/

So far everything works fine. When I tried to execute a meta query locally everything works fine (mysql) and I get the results I expected but on server the query returns no posts.

The content is the same for both databases and the post meta's also.

**CODE:**

```
function rlp_get_posts($post_type = 'post', $num = 10, $offset = 0){

        $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'   => $num,
                'offset'           => $offset,
                'orderby'          => 'id',
                'order'            => 'ASC',
                'post_type'        => $post_type,
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                'key' => 'rlp_native_age',
                'value' => array( 18, 78 ),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                )
             )
                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => false
        );

    return new WP_Query( $args );
}
```

WP_Query requests :

Local

```
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'native' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'rlp_native_age' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '18' AND '78') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Server

```
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'native' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'rlp_native_age' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '18' AND '78') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

The request seems the same. For the moment I don't have access to the db to perform my own SQL queries to target the problem

**EDIT**

When I make a tax_query everything works fine both locally and on the server.

CODE:

```
function rlp_get_posts($post_type = 'post', $num = 10, $offset = 0){

            $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'   => $num,
                    'offset'           => $offset,
                    'orderby'          => 'id',
                    'order'            => 'ASC',
                    'post_type'        => $post_type,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key' => 'sex',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array(71)
                    )
                 )
                    'post_status'      => 'publish',
                    'suppress_filters' => false
            );

        return new WP_Query( $args );
    }
```

WP_Query server request (same as local) :

```
[request] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (71) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'native' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has a bug but the author of the plugin propose a workaround until he fix it.

I tested the workaround and is working as expected.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'rlp_native_age',
        'value'   => 18,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '>='
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'rlp_native_age',
        'value'   => 78,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '<='
    )
)
```

**Post thread and solution :**

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-meta-query-not-working?replies=3